Why in Srimad Bhagvatam 8.12.25, Shiva forces on a woman?
Srimad Bhagvatam 8:12:25
https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/8/12/26?d=1
The beautiful woman was already naked, and when She saw Lord Śiva coming toward Her, She became extremely bashful. Thus She kept smiling, but She hid Herself among the trees and did not stand in one place.His senses being agitated, Lord Śiva, victimized by lusty desires, began to follow Her, just as a lusty elephant follows a she-elephant.After following Her with great speed, Lord Śiva caught Her by the b*aid of Her hair and dragged Her near him. Although She was unwilling, he embraced Her with his arms.
Can someone explain?

If you want this ans in video format
here is a vid i found that will help you Video

Being deprived of his wisdom, sense of decency and
discernment, by her, and overcome with erotic passions evoked
by her, he lost his sense of shame and approached her even
while (his divine consort) Parvat! stood gazing.
(Srimad Bhagvatam 8:12:25)

Source
https://dn790000.ca.archive.org/0/items/bhagavatapuranaeng031955ocrmotilalbanasirdass/Bhagavata-Purana-ENG-03-1955-OCR-Motilal-Banasirdass.pdf
The strong illusion, or Maya, that Lord Vishnu created up is the reason behind Lord Shiva's actions towards the woman in the verses—who is actually Lord Vishnu in a female form. Lord Shiva, who is normally detached and self-controlled,, concentrates on the woman for the following reasons:
1)The overwhelming power of Maya, which has the ability to influence even the most spiritually evolved beings, is the primary focus of Lord Vishnu's Maya (Illusion). In order to show the immense power of his Maya, Lord Vishnu purposefully creates this illusion. This Maya is so strong that it influences Lord Shiva's thoughts and causes him to fix his attention on the lovely woman when he takes on her form.
2)Test of Lord Shiva's Detachment: The woman's beauty and allure, a manifestation of Lord Vishnu's Maya, temporarily overcome Shiva despite his profound  detachment. This is not to suggest that Lord Shiva is weak in any way; rather, it is meant to demonstrate how even the most powerful gods are susceptible to the power of divine delusion.
3)Woman Symbolism: The woman represents the peak of desire and attachment. Feminine beauty is frequently portrayed in spiritual traditions as a strong force that can shake even the most self-disciplined people. Lord Shiva is put to the test and shown that he can conquer these desires by Lord Vishnu using this form.
4)Lord Shiva's Realization and Recovery: Lord Shiva eventually discovers that he has been tricked after pursuing the woman and getting attached with her. He quickly regains his composure, detachment, and spiritual clarity once he realizes this. Lord Shiva's ultimate control over desires and his capacity to overcome even the strongest delusions are highlighted by this realization.
5)Moral of the Story: The story aims to highlight the significance of spiritual awareness and detachment as well as the power of Maya. It demonstrates that illusions can affect even gods, but what makes them unique is their capacity to identify and get past them.
In summary, Lord Vishnu's potent Maya is the reason behind Lord Shiva's attention towards the woman. The incident shows how anyone can be influenced by Maya, but it also emphasizes Lord Shiva's capacity to finally rise above this delusion and revert to his actual, detached self. This tale teaches us the value of spiritual awareness and the strength of divine deception.

What does Srimad Bhagavata Purana 8.12.25 mean?
We will have to look the verses after 8.12.25 to be able to answer this question.

Rudra now closely followed the footsteps of the running Mahavishnu of
wonderful deeds. It looked as if Rudra, who was already under the
Cupid's influence, was now routed and completely under the enemy's
domination. As he followed her as an excited bull elephant does a cow
in heat, his potent semen dropped on the ground. O King! Wherever on
the earth the semen of the great divinity dropped , those places
become silver and gold mines. Siva thus pursued her wherever Rishis
were staying - on the banks of rivers and lakes, in woodlands, forests
and mountains, as if to demonstrate to them by example of the need for
guarding against exposure to sexual charms. When his semen was
ejaculated, he realized how the Lord's Maya had completely stupefied
him. He now recovered from that infatuation. Siva was not at all
struck with wonder at the unusual events. For he well understood the
unique power of Mahavishnu, the soul of the world, and that of his
relation to Him - how He, the Lord, is the director, and himself only
the directed.
Seeing Siva serene, free from any shock of sin, Mahavishnu, who now
assumed His real form, was very much pleased and spoke to Him. The
Lord said: 'O great divinity and my dear friend! It is a very
fortunate circumstance that in spite of being completely infatuated by
my deluding power in the form of charming damsel, you have by your own
discrimination been able to overcome it and recover your normal state
of desirelessness. Who except you is there among those of subdued
senses that can, after having once come under its spell, overcome My
Maya, which generates various passions like desire, anger, greed etc.
in the heart?

Srimad Bhagavata Purana 8.12.31-39
What advice does Srimad Bhagavata Purana give about such stories?

O great King! I have narrated to you the stories of many who lived to
make their names famous in their lifetime and then to pass away and
become a memory or a mere name soon after. These narratives are only
the literary device I have used with a view to instil into you the
importance of renunciation and realisation. They have no ultimate
significance in themselves (or are not to be taken as literal facts.)

Srimad Bhagavata Purana XII.3.14
First thing to realize is that this is simply a literary fiction. This story is an allegory according to the Purana. Ejaculation of semen is a dead giveaway that this is fiction because Lord Siva is not a male human with semen. It is not possible for Lord Siva who is pure consciousness to have semen and ejaculate it.
Secondly, we have to realize that Lord Siva stands here for a male jiva. In fact the author says so here, 'He, the Lord, is the director, and himself only the directed'.
Thirdly, the story is a cautionary tale about the difficulty of overcoming Maya to the spiritual aspirant. The same idea of difficulty of overcoming Maya is there in the Gita.

My divine Maya (power) constituted of the three Gunas is
difficult to overcome. Whoever takes refuge in Me alone, in utter
devotion, overcomes it.

Gita 7.14
Finally, I would like to bring to attention of the reader this line, 'The
Lord said: 'O great divinity and my dear friend!'. The author of the Purana realizes that Saivites will be unhappy in depicting Lord Siva as an ordinary Jiva. So he does an U-turn and shows Lords Vishnu and Siva as friends.
